# Excel VBA excessive memory usage with If Not Intersect?

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook contains a sheet with formulas around 50 columns x 50 rows. File itself has around 500kB, no cond. formatting, I avoided volatile functions whenever possible. When I open workbook Excel memory usage is around 180MB, but when I change a cell value which recalculates worksheet it increases up to 2.8GB. The only VBA code I have is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim varray As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ost = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    varray = Range("M1:M200").Value
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(13)) Is Nothing Then   'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A3")) Is Nothing Then -- only act on changes to cells A1 to A3
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        For i = UBound(varray, 1) To LBound(varray, 1) Step -1  'Go backwards
            If i < 4 Then
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If VBA.Len(varray(i, 1)) > 0 Then
                Range(Cells(4, "T"), Cells(4, "BD")).Copy Cells(i, "T")
            Else
                Range(Cells(i, "T"), Cells(i, "BD")).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub
```

I suspect this code is not perfect and make a memory mess. Is it possible to optimize it to decrease memory usage?

Comment: `option explicit` / `dim ost as long` - not that it'll contribute toward the memory issue, just good practice... I would guess that the code triggers itself in an endless loop - perhaps try a quick `dim isActive as boolean` / `IF isActive Then Do Nothing Else [code] End If`? - only a quick glance so far

Comment: Stick `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start, and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end?

Comment: i forgot about that - I was right to start lurking the VBA tags again, slowly slipping from my mind

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` & `Application.EnableEvents = True` makes the code at least 2x slower, but releases memory usage....good starting point

Comment: It worked for the first time, but now after saving file VBA code do not work but memory usage is 150MB. Current code:
```
```Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False '?``` and


```Application.EnableEvents = True``` before End Sub

Comment: I fixed problem with not working code by adding ```EbanbleEvents = True``` in ```If i < 4```. Now, after saving worksheet memory drops. However code is very very slow now.  "Calculating (16 Threads)" with progress in % at the bottom toolbar...what's that? I have never seen that before

Answer (score 0):

It seems something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rChanged As Range

    Set rChanged = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M4", Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "M")))
    If Not rChanged Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        Dim ChangedCell As Range
        Dim rDest As Range
        Dim rClear As Range
        For Each ChangedCell In rChanged.Cells
            If Len(ChangedCell.Value) > 0 Then
                Select Case (rDest Is Nothing)
                    Case True:  Set rDest = Me.Cells(ChangedCell.Row, "T")
                    Case Else:  Set rDest = Union(rDest, Me.Cells(ChangedCell.Row, "T"))
                End Select
            Else
                Select Case (rClear Is Nothing)
                    Case True:  Set rClear = Me.Cells(ChangedCell.Row, "T").Resize(, Me.Range("T:BD").Columns.Count)
                    Case Else:  Set rClear = Union(rClear, Me.Cells(ChangedCell.Row, "T").Resize(, Me.Range("T:BD").Columns.Count))
                End Select
            End If
        Next ChangedCell

        If Not rDest Is Nothing Then Me.Range("T4:BD4").Copy rDest
        If Not rClear Is Nothing Then rClear.ClearContents

        With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```